# BadMethodCallException belongsToMany Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Please i try to make a many to many relationship in Laravel 5.4 but i allways get this error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::categories()

I think my code is fine , and i can't fix it , any help please.

THank you.

THis is my code :

**User model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'user_categorys');
    }

}
```

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_categorys');
    }

}
```

**Call method**

```
$user = User::where('id',$id_user)->first();
            foreach ($request->input("idcategs") as $value) {
                $user->categories()->save($value);
            }
```

Comment: This error is saying you're calling `categories()` on a query builder, not the model.  Are you confident you have `$users` assigned from a `first()` call in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` methods when using many to many relationship to attach or detach models.

If `idcategs` is an array of IDs, do something like:

```
$user = User::find($id_user);
$user->attach($request->idcategs);
```

If it's an array of prepared data, you'll need to create categories first:

```
$categoriesIds = [];
$user = User::find($id_user);
foreach ($request->idcategs as $value) {
    $categoriesIds[] = Category::create($value)->id;
}
$user->attach($categoriesIds);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score -1):

You get it wrong:
If you have a Many to Many relationship one or your relation should be:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'foreign_key');
    }
```

and you will have to define a pivot table category_user